# `lein deploy clojars` hangs

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojars

I've installed GPG4Win, generated keys and pasted my public key into clojars as per the [leiningen gpg readme](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/GPG.md). However, when I `lein deploy clojars`, after asking me for my clojars username and password and printing that it has created the jar, it simply hangs. Typing does nothing.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out it was to do with having a version of pgp packaged with git, which generated keys with a default setting other than "RSA and RSA". Removing it and regenerating the keys solved the problem.